# To what extent can the open gaming license be used commercially?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, ogl

Let's say hypothetically I want to make a videogame based on pathfinder. To what extent can I use their content?

From what I can gather, I can use all mechanics, items, and bestiary, but I can't use any copyrighted content such as artwork, story (such as adventure paths) or proper names? I also assume I can't use the word pathfinder except to say the game is based on its rule set.

Does this sound correct? Am I missing anything?